# Why does my python code return a line break?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, encoding, binary

I am trying to create a binary program in python that can change text to binary and vice versa based on user input. So far, it has been going good until I tried encoding the text, and it just returns no string at all. My decoding works, but my encoding returns an empty string. Please help me debug this.

```
import json

symbols = [" ", "!", '"', "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ":", ";", "<", "=", ">", "?", "@"]
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
upper = list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), letters))
after = ["{", "|", "}", "~"]
symbol_sub = 32
upper_sub = 65
lower_sub = 97
after_sub = 123

choice = input("Do you want to encode text, or decode it? e, or d? ").lower()
if choice == 'e':
    string = input("Type in your text: ")
    allchars = string.split()
    encoded = ''
    for c in allchars:
        if c in symbols:
            i = symbols.index() + symbol_sub
            ibin = bin(i).split('0b')[1]
            encoded += str(" " + ibin)
        elif c in upper:
            i = upper.index() + upper_sub
            ibin = bin(i).split('0b')[1]
            encoded += str(" " + ibin)
        elif c in letters:
            i = lower.index() + lower_sub
            ibin = bin(i).split('0b')[1]
            encoded += str(" " + ibin)
        elif c in after:
            i = after.index() + after_sub
            ibin = bin(i).split('0b')[1]
            encoded += str(" " + ibin)
    print(encoded)

elif choice == 'd':
    string = input("Please input your binary code, each binary string separated by spaces: ")
    allbits = string.split(' ')
    decoded = ''
    for i in allbits:
        b10 = int(i, 2)
        if b10 - after_sub < 0:
            if b10 - lower_sub < 0:
                if b10 - upper_sub < 0:
                    decoded += symbols[b10 - symbol_sub]
                else:
                    decoded += upper[b10 - upper_sub]
            else:
                decoded += letters[b10 - lower_sub]
        else:
            decoded += after[b10 - after_sub]
    print(decoded)
```

I want to make it so if you typed "A)" it would return "1000001 101001".

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `list(string)` to get a list of characters, not `string.split()`
2. `lower` is not defined, I think you meant `letters`
3. All the `.index()` calls are missing an argument (Should be `upper.index(c)` )

After these changes :

```
Do you want to encode text, or decode it? e, or d? e
Type in your text: A)

1000001 101001
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother casting the input string to a list. You can already iterate through it as a string.

Comment: @Immot True, but I added that line since OP was trying to do `allchars = string.split()`